# Why am I getting an error message saying x is not numeric when I'm trying to make a histogram in r

Tags: r, error-handling, histogram

I'm creating a histogram in r, the dataframe I'm using has a column x which is lengths, and a column freq which is how often these lengths occur

*e.g.*

```
  x  freq
1.0     5
2.0     6
```

Looking at the table view in r of the dataframe is says that x "column 1:numeric with range 1:50" and freq "column 2: numeric with range 1-7".

However when I try to make a histogram

```
hist(data.frame)
```

I get the following error message

> Error in hist.default(data.frame) : 'x' must be numeric

Just wondering why this may be and if there's anyway to fix this issue

Comment: `hist()` requires a *vector* of values but you seem to be trying to pass it a data frame or the function `data.frame()` - I can't tell from the information you've provided.  If your data frame is named `dat` and the variable of interest in the data frame is `var1`, use `hist(dat$var1)`.

Comment: Try this: `library(tidyr);`

`df %>% uncount(freq) %>% unlist() %>% hist()`

Answer (score 0):

I took the dataframe you used in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73677168/how-to-create-a-column-of-count-frequency-in-r) . Assuming you created your dataframe here in a similar way. Your x variable will be a factor which is not plotted by the `hist()` function and you first need to convert to a double again. Be careful with converting factors to doubles because you might loose the floating point precision.

```r
df1 <- data.frame("length"=c(1.2,3.5,3.6,3.6))
df2 <- as.data.frame(table(df1$length))
colnames(df2) <- c("length", "count")


hist(df1$length) #histogram
hist(df2$length) #-> Error in hist.default(df2$length) : 'x' must be numeric

class(df1$length) #numeric
typeof(df1$length)#double

typeof(df2$length) #integer
class(df2$length) #factor

#So the conversion is done in the table argument where the different categories are treated as factors.

#Conversion can be done
as.numeric(df2$length) #converts to integers
as.numeric(as.character(df2$length)) #preserves floating point precision

hist(as.numeric(as.character(df2$length))) #histogram
```